# Pattern in regular expressions that match pattern_1 and not match pattern_2?

Tags: python, regex, string

I'd like to write a function that matches in a string and returns all uppercase letters that are not followed by a lowercase letter.

```
def find_sub_string(text, pattern):
        if re.search(pattern,  text):
            return re.findall(pattern,  text)
        else:
            return None
```

Here is an example of a desired output:

```
>>> find_sub_string('AaAcDvFF(G)F.E)f',  pattern)
>>> ['F', 'F', 'G', 'F', 'E']
```

What should be the right pattern in that case?

I tried `pattern='[A-Z][^a-z]`, but it produce the following output `['FF', 'G)', 'F.', 'E)']`, which satisfies the described condition, except it returns two letters except one.

Comment: Thank you, mine question was totally similar to the previously asked question. In my case the answer I was looking for was ```pattern='[A-Z](?![a-z])'``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USe negative look ahead in rgex

```
import re
def find_sub_string(text, pattern):
        if re.search(pattern,  text):
            return re.findall(pattern,  text)
        else:
            return None
find_sub_string('AaAcDvFF(G)F.E)f',  '[A-Z](?![a-z])')
```